# DOM manipulation with JavaScript or jQuery by moving element inside of its sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a big list of DOM elements containing product image and description.
How can I use JavaScript or jQuery to move `.title` element inside its sibling's `imageWrapper` element ?

I drew a diagram here, hopefully that helps with explaining the situation.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var $titleArray = $('.title');

for (var i = 0 ; i < $titleArray; i++){
    var $imageWrapper = $($titleArray[i]).parent().prev();
    $($titleArray[i]).appendTo($imageWrapper);  
};
```

[image]

Comment: Post what you've tried so far.

Comment: @ Alon Eitan , @ Utkanos
I just update the post. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! I forgot to put `.length` after `$titleArray` and I used `appendTo()` instead of `prependTo()`. Although the code doesn't look so elegant now. But it's a good start.

```
var $titleArray = $('.title');

for (var i = 0 ; i < $titleArray.length; i++){
    var $imageWrapper = $($titleArray[i]).parent().prev();
    $($titleArray[i]).prependTo($imageWrapper);  
};
```